# Rewrite domain to cut its URI

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, wordpress

I need to set up the domain.com/wp1/ to be shown like domain.com/ I have tried to set up any rewrite in the past hours, but no success :(

P.S. There is a wordpress installed in the public_html/wp1, configured to work on domain.com/wp1/ URL. Its .htaccess is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in tons!

Answer (score 0):

did you tried :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did not the job...
I have managed to accomplish it by adding this:

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /folder/$1 [L]
```

This has done the job.